create and update group row sums on pandas dataframe
i have a dataframe with students and their school subjects:



Subject
Mark




Helen



Art
20


Philosophy
16.8


Economics
12


Colin



Maths
19.2


Geography
17


History
15



For every subject, there is a different weighting, which changes by semester and affects the student's total:



Subject
Weight




Art
0.1


Philosophy
0.6


Economics
0.2


Maths
0.5


Geography
0.01


Philosophy
0.5


History
0.3


Maths
0.6



i was thinking of implementing some sort of vlook up wing the join method, but then since the weightings change, i would have to update the table.
However i would like to print the output in a file as i go through the weights table. in that case, i understand i can use for loops but that is not the most optimised method.
Is there any type of lamda i can use for this case?
Additionally is there any way to identify when each student's total changes, and output that? I was thinking creating sub groups from the data frame and then checking the cumulative sum?
Essentially while iterating through the weights table above, i would like my output to be:
Subject = Mark*Weight but to also account and track the changes in the student totals, so:
 Art: 0.2 
 Philosophy: 10.08 
 Economics: 2.4
Helen: 12.68
 Maths: 9.6 
 Geography: 0.17 
 Philosophy:8.4 
Helen:11 
 History:4.5 
Colin: 14.27
 Maths:11.52 
Colin:16.19


I would suggest starting by reshaping your data so that the first dataframe is Student, Subject, Mark and the second is Semester, Subject, Weight.  This will make it much easier to control merging and grouping

You shouldn't use internal headers in pandas. While possible, this is an anti-pattern. Use a MultiIndex

Also, you have two weights for "Maths", how should you handle that?

@mozway, when a new weight comes in the value is recalculated (so it will be mark*new_weight) and hence the student total will need to be recalculated

@Chris i do not have semester data, it is random when the weightings will change, the best way to describe it would be as if having a continuous input

So what if two person have the same Subject?

@mozway then their totals would change as soon as the new weight comes in

It would improve clarity if you could provide a for loop version of your code and update your example to demonstrate how the output should look like if the two students share a common Subject

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

While not ideal to have internal headers, you could compute the expected output with a combination of map+mul, isna and groupby.transform:
# build mapping series with unique Subjects
s = weights.drop_duplicates('Subject').set_index('Subject')['Weight']

# compute the weighted Mark
df['Weighted_Mark'] = df['Mark'].mul(df['Subject'].map(s))

# identify Names
m = df['Mark'].isna()
# compute total
df.loc[m, 'Weighted_Mark'] = (df.groupby(m.cumsum())['Weighted_Mark']
                                .transform('sum')
                              )

Output:
      Subject  Mark  Weighted_Mark
0       Helen   NaN          14.48
1         Art  20.0           2.00
2  Philosophy  16.8          10.08
3   Economics  12.0           2.40
4       Colin   NaN          14.27
5       Maths  19.2           9.60
6   Geography  17.0           0.17
7     History  15.0           4.50


Thank you for this solution, but it is not what i am looking for, i actually need the values to print in the terminal or a file in the sequence where the changes come in

so when a new weight comes in, a new mark for that subject is printed and the new student total is calculated with the new subject mark, as i have in the desired output

i have not been able to successfully implement it, and hence it does not work, but it looks something like: for i in range(len(weights_table)):  if math.isnan(weights_table.loc[i,"Weight"]: #add the student name to defaultdict and the subjects that are following until a new Mark row is empty
